# Linq2SQL: Select only some columns, but still able to submit changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I need to update a column in a table which contains a lot of rows. Each row has a some large TEXT columns in it, which i do not need for my update.

I'm using LinqPAD, and this is roughly, what i wanna do:

```
(from s in Table
where s.FK_ID == null 
select new{s.FK_ID, s.Datum, s.PBNummer}).ToList()

.ForEach(s => s.FK_ID = new Guid(...some new guid here...));

SubmitChanges();
```

This does not compile, as the properties of an anonymous class type are read-only.

If I do

```
(from s in Table
where s.FK_ID == null 
select s).ToList()
```

then I can update and save, but all columns are loaded, which takes a very long time and causes memory problems.

Is there a way to only load some columns but still have an object that i can update and save using `SubmitChanges`? Or do i have to switch to SQL statements?

Comment: Why do you need to do this via linq-2-sql? Can't you just issue a raw query?

Comment: @alexn The 'new Guid()' part is more complicated as shown in my example here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you don't have a primary key in the database, then you wouldn't be able to update via Linq-To-Sql. If you have a primary key, but just don't know which it is, you can find it in Linqpad by doing something like

```
var table =  (from t in Mapping.GetTables() 
              where t.TableName == "[Table]" select t).SingleOrDefault();

(from dm in table.RowType.DataMembers 
           where dm.DbType != null && dm.IsPrimaryKey 
           select dm.Name)
          .Dump("Primary Key");
```

Once you know the primary key, you can do something like the following, (I'm assuming the primary key is called Id)

```
var oldList = (from s in Table
          where s.FK_ID == null 
          select new{s.Id , s.FK_ID, s.Datum, s.PBNummer}).ToList() ;
```

This is similar to your query, except I have added the primary key

```
foreach(var r in oldList)
{
    Table t = new Table();
    t.Id        = r.Id ;

    Table.Attach(t);
    t.FK_ID   = new Guid(...some new guid here...));
}
SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: That's close to the final solution. Regarding to [link](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/updating-a-single-column-in-linq-to-sql-using-attach/) you have to attach a second new object with the same id but different data to the context and then submit it. That finally worked. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: The example in this link you mention seems counter-intuitive, since you would expect that ID would end up with "some random value". I don't deny that it works, but I can't explain why it works. However, I realise I did have an error in my example (should be fixed now), in that you need to first attach the new record and then make your changes.

Comment: I agree it's counter-intuitive but it works. I presume the parameters are handled from last to first.

Your edited version makes more sense and i will check if it works tomorrow, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Way to update specific columns of a database record in Linq to SQL is to create a View on the table containing large columns, and only include the “short” columns:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_FooMax] AS
SELECT  OID, ID
FROM    dbo.FooMax
```

Since views based on single tables are updatable, an update on the view is performed as an update on the table:

```
using (var database = new DataContext())
{
  var fooView = database.V_FooMaxes
    .Where(foo => foo.OID == OID).FirstOrDefault();
  fooView.ID = newID;
  database.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Reference: http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/updating-a-single-column-in-linq-to-sql-using-a-view/

Also you can look at: http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/updating-a-single-column-in-linq-to-sql-summary/

Comment: This does not seem to work in LinqPad, where the mapping is automatically generated by LinqPad itself. The article you mentioned says:

_When mapping views in a .dbml file, you must take care of:

* definition of a primary key column
_

I have no .dbml file and didn't find a way to define the primary key column in LinqPad.